# how to make a simple subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table schema like this

**mysql> desc material_out;**

```
`enter code here`
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| barcode     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| qty         | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| unit        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| num_letter  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| destination | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**mysql> desc material_in;**

```
`enter code here`
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| barcode     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| qty         | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| unit        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| num_letter  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| destination | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**mysql> desc goods;**

```
`enter code here`
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| barcode     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| unit        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| category    | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| first_stok  | double    )  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In table material_out I have data of 10,000 rows. and has as many as 350 types of barcodes.
In table material_in I have data around 15,000 rows. and has as many as 200 types of barcodes.

but i have a problem when doing a query. takes a long time probably about 3 hours.

I think this is not efficient when you want to print a report.

**my query like this.**

```
SELECT br.barcode,
       out.total_out,
       in.total_in,
       out.total_out - in.total_in AS RESULT
FROM
  (SELECT barcode,
          name,
          first_stok,
          unit
   FROM goods
   WHERE category=1) AS br
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     (SELECT sum(qty)
      FROM material_out
      WHERE date >= '2013-08-15'
        AND tanggal <='2013-08-20'
        AND barcode=a.barcode) AS total_out
   FROM material_out a
   GROUP BY a.barcode) AS OUT ON OUT.barcode=br.barcode
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     (SELECT sum(qty)
      FROM material_in
      WHERE date >= '2013-08-15'
        AND tanggal <='2013-08-20'
        AND barcode=a.barcode) AS total_in
   FROM material_in a
   GROUP BY a.barcode) AS IN ON IN.barcode=br.barcode
```

edited bro..
new query from realitygone.

```
<pre>
mysql> SELECT tNEW.barcode,
    ->     tNEW.total_out, tNEW.total_in, tNEW.result,
    ->     tOLD.total_out AS total_out_old, tOLD.total_in AS total_in_old, tNEW.total_in +  tOLD.total_in - tNEW.total_out - tOLD.total_out as sum_total
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT goods.barcode,
    ->         SUM(tOUT.qty) AS total_out,
    ->         SUM(tIN.qty) AS total_in,
    ->         SUM(tIN.qty) - SUM(tOUT.qty) AS result
    ->     FROM goods
    ->     LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=goods.barcode
    ->     LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.kode=goods.barcode
    ->     WHERE goods.category=1
    ->         AND tOUT.date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31'
    ->         AND tIN.date BETWEEN '2013-05-1' AND '2013-08-31'
    ->     GROUP BY goods.barcode
    -> ) AS tNEW
    -> LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT goods.barcode,
    ->         SUM(tOUT.qty) AS total_out,
    ->         SUM(tIN.qty) AS total_in
    ->     FROM goods
    ->     LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=goods.barcode
    ->     LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.kode=goods.barcode
    ->     WHERE goods.category=1
    ->         AND tOUT.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-04-31'
    ->         AND tIN.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-04-31'
    ->     GROUP BY goods.barcode
    -> ) AS tOLD ON tOLD.barcode=tNEW.barcode;
+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|   barcode   | total_out | total_in | result     | total_out_old | total_in_old      | sum_total          |
+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| CG003       |      2720 |    14400 |      11680 |         17588 |             92160 |              86252 |
| CG009       |       144 |      720 |        576 |          NULL |              NULL |               NULL |
| CG010       |       596 |     1800 |       1204 |          1512 |              6048 |               5740 |
| CG011       |       864 |     4320 |       3456 |          1156 |              3600 |               5900 |
| CG012       |      1875 |     7560 |       5685 |           843 |              4680 |               9522 |
| CG013       |      2520 |     7560 |       5040 |          2826 |             14400 |              16614 |
| CG014       |     19320 |   314340 |     295020 |         39312 |            597312 |             853020 |
| CG015       |       890 |     9750 |       8860 |         12003 |            183330 |             180187 |
| CG017       |        24 |   102000 |     101976 |            26 |               420 |             102370 |
| CG018       |    390000 |   273000 |    -117000 |       1320000 |           1020000 |            -417000 |
| CG020       |       396 |     2170 |       1774 |           820 |              3656 |               4610 |
| CG022       |       238 |     1200 |        962 |           330 |               800 |               1432 |
| CG023       |       752 |     3600 |       2848 |          3585 |             21600 |              20863 |
| CG024       |     21560 |   146068 |     124508 |         64095 | 361552.6000000002 |  421965.6000000002 |
| CG025       |     14833 |    85992 |      71159 |         49049 | 230218.0000000009 | 252328.00000000093 |
| CG026       |       172 |     4000 |       3828 |           766 |              1170 |               4232 |
| CG028       |       126 |     1440 |       1314 |            41 |               660 |               1933 |
| CG029       |        18 |      300 |        282 |            40 |               920 |               1162 |
| CG030       |        50 |      720 |        670 |            50 |               780 |               1400 |
| CHDRY001    |     10260 |    81000 |      70740 |         73440 |            936000 |             933300 |
| CHDRY002    |   4071288 |  3477926 |    -593362 |       9762598 |           8570238 |           -1785722 |
| CHDRY003    |      8880 |     4441 |      -4439 |          NULL |              NULL |               NULL |
| CHDRY004    |     48960 |   238590 |     189630 |        119880 |            413850 |             483600 |
| CHDRY005    |       144 |      144 |          0 |           256 |               256 |                  0 |
| CHDRY006    |     37440 |   211200 |     173760 |        164160 |            968000 |             977600 |
| CHDRY007    |    237600 |  1679040 |    1441440 |        604890 |           4758600 |            5595150 |
| CHDRY009    |    766080 |  2026160 |    1260080 |        698250 |           2151560 |            2713390 |
| CHDRY010    |      3600 |   168000 |     164400 |         40800 |           1488000 |            1611600 |
| CHDRY012    |       200 |     2700 |       2500 |           340 |              5600 |               7760 |
| CHDRY013    |      4290 |    17600 |      13310 |          4290 |             21120 |              30140 |
| CHDRY014    |    278300 |   643720 |     365420 |        466210 |           1243620 |            1142830 |
| CHDRY015    |     78720 |   264100 |     185380 |         81840 |            367070 |             470610 |
| CHDRY018    |   2431270 |  1987260 |    -444010 |       4877450 |           4672689 |            -648771 |
| CHDRY022    |      1320 |     4840 |       3520 |           330 |              1650 |               4840 |
| CHDRY023    |       200 |      110 |        -90 |          NULL |              NULL |               NULL |
| CHDRY024    |      2000 |     4000 |       2000 |           100 |               100 |               2000 |
| CHDRY025    |      1800 |     4000 |       2200 |          NULL |              NULL |               NULL |
| CHDRY026    |       850 |      850 |          0 |          NULL |              NULL |               NULL |
| CHDRY028    |       120 |      480 |        360 |          NULL |              NULL |               NULL |
| CHPRINT001  |      8000 |   222000 |     214000 |         13800 |            390000 |             590200 |
| CHPRINT002  |      4000 |    10000 |       6000 |          4200 |             21000 |              22800 |
| CHPRINT004  |     13600 |   324000 |     310400 |         14400 |            512000 |             808000 |
| CHPRINT005  |     28800 |   136800 |     108000 |         35000 |            133000 |             206000 |
| CHPRINT006  |      3100 |    93000 |      89900 |          5600 |            112000 |             196300 |
| CHPRINT007  |     16800 |    69000 |      52200 |          2000 |              9000 |              59200 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</pre>
```

hello guy, i have new problem.  when i calculate field `tNEW.total_in +  tOLD.total_in - tNEW.total_out - tOLD.total_out.` 
when meeting with the column contains null, then the result of the sum contains null.
for example in
barcode CHDRY025
barcode CHDRY003
barcode CHDRY028
barcode NWDRY004

for admin or moderator, sorry if I break the rules. :-)

====================== POST EDITED 30 September 2013 ======================================

Hello RealityGone,
I have used a query from you. the result is going well. but when I try to enter new data. I then re-query of your display. but the results are not in accordance with the entered data.
for example, when I enter a query from you. The following results

```
+----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
|    barcode           | total_out | total_in | result     | total_out_old | total_in_old      |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
| TNWET021             |      6195 |    15000 |       8805 |         20085 |             46200 |
| TNWET020             |      3420 |     7650 |       4230 |          4860 |             23925 |
| TNWET019             |      8370 |    25200 |      16830 |         11610 |             47175 |
| TNWET018             |     18690 |    44100 |      25410 |         13800 |             54150 |
| TNWET017             |      1140 |     3750 |       2610 |          3690 |             16200 |
| TNWET016             |     19500 |    56100 |      36600 |         31725 |            111300 |
| TNWET015             |      5145 |    18150 |      13005 |          6510 |             23400 |
| TNWET014             |     33300 |    65250 |      31950 |         96300 |            262500 |
| TNWET013             |      1170 |     5625 |       4455 |          3690 |             13200 |
| TNWET012             |       720 |     2700 |       1980 |          3870 |             13800 |
| TNWET011             |         0 |        0 |          0 |           180 |               450 |
| TNWET010             |         0 |        0 |          0 |           405 |              1125 |
| TNWET009             |         0 |        0 |          0 |             0 |                 0 |
```

when I do a manual summation and results like this.

```
mysql> select sum(qty) from material_in where barcode='TNWET021' and date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31';
+-------------+
|   sum(qty)  |
+-------------+
|         750 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select sum(qty) from material_in where barcode='TNWET020' and date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31';
+-------------+
|   sum(qty)  |
+-------------+
|         450 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your query even does what I think it is supposed to do. You didn't specify what output you expect in your question but I assume you want the SUM() of the qty fields in the two material tables for each of the barcodes in the goods table. (I've also assumed the 'tanggal' field is the same as the date field above it since it isn't in your EXPLAIN output and it means date in english.)

You certainly don't need the subqueries in the SELECT statements of the table expressions you're joining to. I also don't see why those need to be table expressions at all. I'm not surprised that query runs incredibly slow. It is correlated subqueries in joined table expressions.

I don't think you even need a subquery at all. This is my simplified version:

```
SELECT goods.barcode,
    SUM(tOUT.qty) AS total_out,
    SUM(tIN.qty) AS total_in,
    SUM(tOUT.qty)-SUM(tIN.qty) AS result
FROM (
```

goods
    LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=goods.barcode
    LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.barcode=goods.barcode
    WHERE g.category=1
        AND tOUT.date BETWEEN '2013-08-15' AND '2013-08-20'
        AND tIN.date BETWEEN '2013-08-15' AND '2013-08-20'
    GROUP BY g.barcode

There may be a better way to do this but this is how I would quickly put two date ranges together like you're asking:

```
SELECT tNEW.barcode,
    tNEW.total_out, tNEW.total_in,
    tNEW.total_out-tNEW.total_in AS result,
    COALESCE(tOLD.total_out,0) AS total_out_old, COALESCE(tOLD.total_in,0) AS total_in_old
FROM (
    SELECT g.barcode,
        COALESCE(SUM(tOUT.qty),0) AS total_out,
        COALESCE(SUM(tIN.qty),0) AS total_in
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT barcode
        FROM goods
    ) AS g
    LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=g.barcode
    LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.barcode=g.barcode
    WHERE g.category=1
        AND tOUT.date BETWEEN '2013-08-15' AND '2013-08-20'
        AND tIN.date BETWEEN '2013-08-15' AND '2013-08-20'
    GROUP BY g.barcode
) AS tNEW
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT g.barcode,
        SUM(tOUT.qty) AS total_out,
        SUM(tIN.qty) AS total_in
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT barcode
        FROM goods
    ) AS g
    LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=g.barcode
    LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.barcode=g.barcode
    WHERE g.category=1
        AND tOUT.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-04-31'
        AND tIN.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-04-31'
    GROUP BY g.barcode
) AS tOLD ON tOLD.barcode=tNEW.barcode
```

Comment: wowww Amazing...

You have helped me.

you truly simple query and it only took 0.2 seconds

Comment: I want to ask again, what if the case I want to display the results in the period. **for example: material_out from the date '2013-08-15 'AND '2013-08-20' was added to the period 1 from 1 January to 31 April. but the results will be shown with different columns**

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you. The original query would have been running each of the subqueries in your joins for every row in the goods table (because of the correlated subqueries). That is why it was so slow. Row By Agonizing Row.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to add 3 columns that show the same information but for a different date range?

Comment: sorry if my question poorly understood, because I translated using google translate. I mean is I want to add 2 more columns. ** now that there is a barcode, total_out, total_in and result** . _italic_ I want 2 column again _italic_ total_out_old and total_in_old .  derived from the contents of total_out_old from material_out with the period of 1 January to 31 April.

Comment: columns displayed so there are 4 columns: barcode, total_out, total_in , total_out_old and result

Comment: See the edit above. There may be a niftier, more concise way of doing it but that will get it together and it shouldn't be slow at all (just like running the query twice).

Comment: hello @RealityGone i have new problem. I have edited my question. and you can see my new problem :-)

Comment: You should probably make a new question for this kind of thing. But I've added some COALESCE() statements to make sure that there is always a value in the column since working with NULLs always gives you NULL.

Comment: update: I've moved the COALESCE() functions in the tOLD table expression to the outside query. In cases where there is a barcode in tNEW that isn't in tOLD you'll get NULL values in your result set.

Comment: sorry I just replied. because it can only be connected to the Internet. well, I will try to

Comment: I have tried from your query. and the results were amazing. according to the results I want. I say many thanks to you

Comment: hello @RealityGone , i have new problem. and I've changed my post

Comment: sorry if I ask a lot. because if one of the results will be fatal

Comment: My guess is that each barcode exists multiple times in the goods table. I had assumed goods only held one entry for each barcode. If goods contains the barcode more than once it will count all of the entries in material_in and material_out for each of the times it appears in the goods table. However, that still doesn't really make sense since the number you got isn't a factor of the number my query returns. I've updated my query to only use the unique barcodes from the goods table which should remove any double counting from duplicates there.

Comment: If that doesn't work then you will need to investigate your data to try to figure out where the issue is coming from. Check the fields the tables join on and the values that are being summed.

Comment: I have tried to query from you but there is an error. like this : 
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'goods.category' in 'where clause'

Comment: the goods table is now aliased as 'g' in order to avoid confusion. i've updated the query in my answer....

Comment: I also have tried to change the initial table as g . but the result is still the same error

Comment: If you had actually looked at the query for places that said `goods.category` where it should have said `g.category` you would have found that the WHERE clause of the tNEW table expression had a place where it needed to be changed to `g.category`. I've updated the query... again.

Comment: may be missed if tried immediately. May I have your email? then will I give the login info and access to mysql

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have time to do your work for you. I recommend picking up a good book on TSQL so you can actually start to understand what it is my queries are doing. (I recommend TSQL Fundamentals 2012 by Itzik Ben-Gan.) Actually understanding it will help you go a lot further than getting someone else to do it for you. I hope you figure it out. Good luck.

Comment: until now i can't solvve my problem